# Regular Expressions - Pattern and Matcher with roups

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have input string to process of the format

```
xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:filters:6:item:xxx
```

Where `xxx` could by any combination of alphanumerics and underscore.

I am trying to capture the number between `filters` and `item` using regular expressions.

I have the regular expression `\\S*filters:(\\d+):item\\S*` and it matches OK but I cannot work out how to extract the number.

The test code

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('\\S*filters:(\\d+):item\\S*');
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher('aaaaab:filters:3:item:foo');
system.debug(myMatcher.matches());
system.debug(myMatcher.groupCount());
system.debug(myMatcher.group(0));
```

outputs the following:

```
true
1
aaaaab:filters:3:item:foo
```

as you see, the group has captured who whole string, not just the number which I want.

How do I get the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first match is the entire pattern. So in this case you'd want the second match. Try:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('\\S*filters:(\\d+):item\\S*');
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher('aaaaab:filters:3:item:foo');
system.debug(myMatcher.group(1));
```

And you'll get the output 3.

It's a bit confusing since the group count says there is only one group. However, that's the way the group count is defined. It doesn't include the entire pattern. (See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_groupCount)

Kudos for getting the regex right. I always find that the hard part.